# Can value at risk be computed using downside deviation?

Tags: value-at-risk

Value at risk is usually computed with a regular standard deviation. But can it be computed using downside deviation (semi-deviation) instead? Particularly if I want to consider a Var that includes the drift of the future returns of the portfolio?

The reason I wonder is because volatility (standard deviation) tends to rise when prices are falling. If a portfolio contains a short position on an asset whose price is falling, the portfolio will gain. But the increase in volatility will push up the VaR estimate, making it seem like the risk has gone up. Over longer time horizons, a negative drift in that case could counterbalance the volatility, but if the volatility is high, it'll dominate the drift and keep the VaR elevated.

Computed with a downside deviation, the VaR wouldn't necessarily go up in such a scenario, and the risk wouldn't be "over-estimated".

Thanks for any insights as to whether this is possible and if this makes sense mathematically or otherwise.